# How to indicate position of a <tr> table row in a dynamic table list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would want to show the index of my table list without the on click that are in most examples here in SO and other sources.

```
<script src="../js/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableID" width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="sm">5</td>
    <td class="pos"></td>
  </tr>     
  <tr>
    <td class="sm">4</td>
    <td class="pos"></td>
  </tr>   
  <tr>
    <td class="sm">5</td>
    <td class="pos"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
var position  = getElementsByClassName("pos").index();;
document.getElementsByClassName("pos")[0].textContent = position;
</script>
```

I would want the above table to give a result like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
$('td.pos').each(function(){
$(this).html($(this).parent().index()+1);
});
```

Here is the [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/je6r29qa/)